# Не работает выпадающий список плагина Chosen при динамическом добавлении выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, chosen

Если выпадающий список изначально задан на странице все прекрасно работает, а если он добавляется на страницу позднее, тогда плагин не срабатывает.
Я так понимаю проблема в том, что код плагина в js выполняется только при загрузке страницы, как можно пов
тор запустить код плагина при динамическом добавление выпадающего списка?

Список добавляется так по нажатию кнопки

```
  var div = $('<div/>', {'class': 'DynamicExtraField' + s
                }).appendTo($('#DynamicExtraFieldsContainer' + s));
$("    <select id='bears2' data-placeholder='Выберете тэги...' class='chosen-select'  multiple tabindex='4'><option value=''></option><option value='Привет'>Привет</option></select>").appendTo(div);
```

Код плагина js

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js

[image: Неправильная работа] Неправильная работа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Нормальная работа

Плагин меняет и добавляет элементы на страницу.

Вообще этот плагин нужен  для реализации выбора тегов или создания новых
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему его не активировать плагин, сразу после того, как появляется список, например привязав его к какому-то событию ?

Comment: @NeedHate в том и вопрос как его активировать файл плагина при добавлении списка?

Comment: а как список добавляется? код?

Comment: @NeedHate добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ решения довольно кустарный, но, думаю, это поможет создать правильную логику:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const newPlaceForSelect = document.querySelector('.newplaceforselect');
const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');

const newSelect = document.createElement('select');
newSelect.innerHTML = `
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
     `;


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 newPlaceForSelect.appendChild(newSelect);
 $(newSelect).chosen();
})
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
 padding: 2rem;
}

.newplaceforselect {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <button>Add featured select</button>
 <h3>After this block will be added new Select block</h3>
 <div class="newplaceforselect"></div>
</div>
```